# How to install wireless dongle?

Tags: wireless

Good morning to all Ubuntu users. About 24 hours ago, I changed the operating system from Windows to Linux. While I used to be able to play around with anything in  windows, now I feel like I am having difficulties. Should I install the drivers for my wireless dongle? 
I lost the installation CD and when I try the web to find the drivers, the system tells me that it is impossible to open the files.

Could anyone explain to me step by step what to do? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which Dongle it is?

Comment: Sitecom Wl-352 V2 002

Comment: I do not know how to do

Comment: In order to propose a solution, we need further details which you may add by editing your question. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run and add: uname -r and also: lsusb Welcome to Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1):

32 bit works but 64 bit drivers reported not to work.

It has been reported that there is a native driver from the manufacturer. (download mirrored at [Unbolt](https://www.unbolt.net/downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v7_0.20100628.tar.gz))

You need two modification to make the driver work:

- Modify the Makefile line 3: export TOPDIR := $(shell pwd)
- Add the Sitecom USB ID for the WL-352 device to the file

os_intf/linux/usb_intf.c: {USB_DEVICE(0x0DF6, 0x004C)},